# Finding Matching Values Between Multiple Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So i wanna create a dataframe based on the matching values between 11 others with the reference dataframe.
And the 11 dataframes has a column named 'Serial Number' which i wanna compare with the Serial ID column on the reference dataframe.

Due to the fact that i didn't thought of way to loop all 12 excel files into separated variables. I just writed the below code.

Imported all libraries needed

```
import pandas as pd

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Specified the path in which all the excel files are stored

```
directory = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Ursa project'
```

And did `filename = pd.read_excel('path')` for all 12 files

Now that i created all dataframe objects i need to find which rows of these 11 dataframes has matching values between the Serial Number column with the Serial ID column in the reference dataframe.

My failed attempt was to do the following for each dataframe:

```
for i in reference_df['Serial ID']:

  df_matches = df1[df1['Serial number'] == i]

df_matches
```

P.S.: i'm using Colab

One of the excel files i'm using is too long so here's a drive link to both Serial ID and Serial Number: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BBTnQY1Be6vHtrrPQyXE18eVPkGU_X5N?usp=sharing

Comment: what would your expected outcome look like?

Comment: I think one of the problems i'm stumbling upon would be the fact that although there's matching between the 'Serial Number' columns and the Serial ID column, those matches aren't exact matches. 
So let's say if 1001 is present on  both columns, but in the Serial Number cell we have "s/n:1001" and in the Serial ID cell we have just "1001"

The code won't understand it as a match, so how do i go about to filter these little differences?

Comment: Perhaps you can add sample data for us to try it? It will be better for us to help you

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to match is a part of a string, you can use `df.Series.str.contains`.

```
df_matches = []
for i in reference_df['Serial ID']:
    df_matches.append(df1[df1['Serial number'].str.contains(i)])
```

Comment: That's an interesting alternative, however trying that i'm geting "Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values" so i searched it and learned that i just need to use fillna() or dropna().
And even after that and checking if the NaN values dropped the same error accurs.

Comment: @ObinaryName1 if you don't mind, would you share a sample of your data in the post?

Comment: Yeah, i've added a link to both files i'm using beacause one of them is too long and a sample of it would require for me to know where the matches are.

Comment: @ObinaryName1 It looks like both your serial ID and serial number dataframe have `Nan` values, while doing `dropna` to both the dataframe, you need to make sure you put the argument `inplace=True` so that it will stay as desired

Comment: Even after doing df.dropna(inplace=True) for both dfs i'm testing the error "Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values" keeps coming up. And i actually ran a check for NaN values on both.
I did df['column'].isnull().values.any() on both of them and FALSE was the response. So there aren't any Nan values.

Comment: Have you make sure each and every data frames has performed dropna()?

Comment: Yes! I'm trying with only two, so if i find out how to make it work i'll do it for the others. But nothing 'till now. I considered doing merge so i can use "how = 'inner'" to get the intersection between both columns but i keep getting #check for duplicates, keyError: 'Serial_ID'

Comment: I'm check if filling the blank spaces in the excel file will do it, because sincerely i don't have more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I used merge and it worked!

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2, on=["Desirable Column"], how='inner')
```

and it got the intersection between both dataframes. So to try and get the values that aren't in the reference dataframe (df2) i had to concatenate df3 with df1 and remove_duplicates and what it delivered to me was all values that are in the df1 but not in df2. Exactly what i wanted.

I did de below:

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,3]})
df1=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,3,4,5]})
```

in:

```
df3= pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['A'])
df3
```

out:

```
df3=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,3,3]})
```

in:

```
df4=pd.concat([df1,df3]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
df4
```

out:

```
df4=pd.DataFrame({'A':[4,5]})
```